# Python3.x + Selenium как листать

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Мне нужно пролистать страницу и нажать на элемент.
Не могу понять, как листать страницу с помощью selenium?..
Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне помог этот метод

`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250);")` пролистать вверх на 250 пиксилей

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно прокрутить к целевому элементу, можно воспользоваться методом [.move_to_element()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element) из **ActionChains**, пример:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/')
target = driver.find_element_by_link_text('BROWSE TEMPLATES')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(target)
actions.perform()
```

Для прокрутки в конец (начало) страницы через [.send_keys()](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.w3schools.com/')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
# send_keys(Keys.HOME), если в начало
# так тоже сработает:
# send_keys(Keys.DOWN) send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
# send_keys(Keys.UP) send_keys(Keys.PAGE_UP)
```

Для прокрутки на заданное количество пикселей метод окна [.scrollBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy):

```py
scroll_vаlue = -200
scroll_by = f'window.scrollBy(0, {scroll_vаlue});'
driver.execute_script(scroll_by)
```

Comment: А если нужно просто пролистать?

Comment: нет типо на 200 пикселей вниз так можно?

Comment: можно по пискселям пролистать вниз или вверх?

Comment: хорошо сейчас проверю

Comment: не работает просто останавливается и не хочет листать вот код: import selenium
from selenium import *

option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
driver.get('https://browser-info.ru/')

scroll_vаlue = -200
scroll_by = f'window.scrollBy(0, {scroll_vаlue});'
driver.execute_script(scroll_by)

Comment: @Никита поспите перед скроллом ))

Comment: не листает все равно